# DMOJ COCI '08 Contest 1 #2

Tags: python, testing, logic

I have figured out the bulk of the logic of this [problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/coci08c1p2) but i can't figure out why my code fails one of the tests. If somebody can help me that would be great. Here's my code:

```
n = int(input())
ans = input()
adrian = 'ABC'
bruno = 'BABC'
goran = 'CCAABB'
score_adrian = 0
score_bruno = 0
score_goran = 0
output = ''
for i in range(n):
    if ans[i] == adrian[i % 3]:
        score_adrian = score_adrian + 1
    if ans[i] == bruno[i % 4]:
        score_bruno = score_bruno + 1
    if ans[i] == goran[i % 6]:
        score_goran = score_goran + 1

if score_adrian > score_bruno and score_adrian > score_goran:
    output = str(score_adrian) + '\nAdrian'
elif score_bruno > score_adrian and score_bruno > score_goran:
    output = str(score_bruno) + '\nBruno'
elif score_goran > score_adrian and score_goran > score_bruno:
    output = str(score_goran) + '\nGoran'

elif score_adrian == score_bruno and score_adrian > score_goran:
    output = str(score_adrian) + '\nAdrian\nBruno'
elif score_adrian == score_goran and score_adrian > score_bruno:
    output = str(score_goran) + '\nAndrian\nGoran'
elif score_goran == score_bruno and score_bruno > score_adrian:
    output = str(score_goran) + '\nBruno\nGoran'
elif score_adrian == score_bruno and score_bruno == score_goran:
    output = str(score_adrian) + '\nAdrian\nBruno\nGoran'
print(output)
```

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be simpler?

```
n = int(input())
ans = input()
adrian = 'ABC'
bruno = 'BABC'
goran = 'CCAABB'
score_adrian = 0
score_bruno = 0
score_goran = 0
output = ''
for i in range(n):
    if ans[i] == adrian[i % 3]:
        score_adrian = score_adrian + 1
    if ans[i] == bruno[i % 4]:
        score_bruno = score_bruno + 1
    if ans[i] == goran[i % 6]:
        score_goran = score_goran + 1
max_number = max(score_adrian, score_bruno, score_goran)
print(max_number)
if score_adrian == max_number:
    print("Adrian")
if score_bruno == max_number:
    print("Bruno")
if score_goran == max_number:
    print("Goran")
```

Comment: thank you soo much for taking the time out of the day to help me. I am still learning python and wasn't introduced to the max function yet, but now i know about it and it simplified the code soo much. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @ammiko Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)